# Proof: $(\sup(A) - \epsilon)^n<y<(\sup(A)+\epsilon)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Prop.**: *let be $y \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$, $n \in \Bbb{N}_{>0}$, and $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, then: $$A=\{x| x \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}\wedge x^n \leq y \} \Rightarrow (\sup(A) - \epsilon)^n< y<(\sup(A)+\epsilon)^n, \text{ forall }0<\epsilon <\sup(A)$$*

**Proof**: I must prove $$[1] \quad \quad \quad \quad(\sup(A) - \epsilon)^n< y, \text{ forall }0<\epsilon <\sup(A)$$$$\quad \quad \quad \quad \wedge$$$$[2] \quad \quad \quad \quad y <(\sup(A)+\epsilon)^n, \text{ forall }0<\epsilon <\sup(A)$$
$[1]$:  I have $\sup(A) \to \forall \epsilon >0(\exists x \in A(\sup(A)-\epsilon<x))$, by hypothesis $0<\epsilon < \sup(A) \to 0<\sup(A)-\epsilon$, therefore $(\sup(A)-\epsilon)^n<x^n$ but $x \in A \to x^n \leq y$ then $(\sup(A)-\epsilon)^n<x^n\leq y \to (\sup(A)-\epsilon)^n< y$

$[2]$:  by contradiction exists $0<\epsilon <\sup(A)(y \geq (\sup(A)+\epsilon)^n)$ therefore $(\sup(A)+\epsilon)^n \leq y$, and by hypothesis $0<\epsilon < \sup(A) \to 0<\epsilon<2\epsilon< \sup(A)+\epsilon$ then $\sup(A)+\epsilon \in A$ (because by contradiction $(\sup(A)+\epsilon)^n \leq y$), but $\sup(A) \in M_\leq(A)$ therefore $\sup(A)+\epsilon \leq \sup(A)$ and it is an absurd

Is it correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is pretty much spotless. But the second one is not clear though. Here's how I would do it.

Let $ \epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary.

$0 \lt \sup A \lt (\sup A + \epsilon )\implies0 \lt (\sup A + \epsilon ) \not \in  A \implies  (\sup A + \epsilon )^n \gt y$ by definition. I also don't understand the need for the stipulation $ \epsilon \lt \sup A $because it is pretty redundant. Hope I helped.

Comment: @Ishaaq, your proof is direct, is it correct?

Comment: Well mostly. A purist might argue the statement $ (\sup A + \epsilon ) \not \in  A  $ might need justification and then you need to use a contradiction. But generally,  yeah I guess it is direct.

Comment: Ishfaaq, of course... by hypothesis $$0<\sup(A)<\sup(A)+ \epsilon$$ and $$\{\sup(A), \sup(A)+\epsilon\} \subseteq M_{\leq}(A) \wedge \sup(A) =\min (M_{\leq}(A))$$ if by contradiction $(\sup(A)+ \epsilon) \in A$ then $$(\sup(A)+\epsilon) \leq \sup(A)$$ and it an absurd because $\sup(A) =\min(M_{\leq}(A))$.. is it correct?

Comment: I'm a little unclear about the notation. Simply if $ (\sup A + \epsilon) \in A $ then $ \sup A + \epsilon \le \sup A \implies \epsilon \le 0$ which is absurd.

Comment: okok :) thanks soo much!